# JOGL FBObject multisampling

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, jogl, multisampling

I am using **JOGL** to develop a simple OpenGL 3D graphics engine. Right now, I've implemented a simple rendering pipeline which renders the scene onto a FBO, which then gets passed to a shader that renders the FBO's color texture to the screen, optionally applying some post-process effect, such as a blur.

Without using FBOs, it's very easy to enable nice-looking multisampling with JOGL. For instance, since I'm hosting my GL panel inside Swing, I'm using a `GLJPanel` and creating it like so, to enable multisampling:

```
GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(null);
caps.setSampleBuffers(true);
caps.setNumSamples(8);
GLJPanel gljp = new GLJPanel(caps);
```

This is pretty straightforward and leads to nice-looking results. However, this isn't very useful when the geometry must first get drawn to a FBO. The best way to do this is to just attach a GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE to the FBO, render the scene, and then performing the multisampling in the fragment shader of the second pass.

Although JOGL provides a rather extensive **FBObject** class to help manage FBOs, I failed to find a way to get it to render to a multisampled texture (it only allows working with `TextureAttachment` objects, which are hardcoded to work only with TEXTURE_2D resources). I thus resorted to simply using the provided FBObject as a skeleton, but doing most of the work with plain gl.gl* calls. I know this isn't hacky or anything, and perhaps a "cleaner" solution would just be to extend `TextureAttachment` and create a class dedicated to multisampled textures.

I'm just wondering - am I missing something, or does JOGL really not support FBOs with multisampled textures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for the same answer, I actually just stopped using FBObjects altogether, and I'm currently using plain old `gl.gl*` commands for managing my framebuffers (including my new deferred renderer's GBuffer).

Comment: Can you take an example of  MSAA in jogl with old gl commands?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this is where I ended up implementing my code for the forward renderer: https://github.com/AndreiBarsan/Yeti/blob/b1084266e5699e2bcfa06b915e6b576a7ca5fb72/src/barsan/opengl/rendering/ForwardRenderer.java#L322